# KDE svn2git aborts with "Error: Writing process fatal: Root cannot be a non-directory"

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

As mentioned in the Title, that's the error I am getting, and that's the only thing I receive. I do not even understand what the error means to even begin with the troubleshooting and I could not find anything of relevance anywhere with Google, SO, even the documentation
Just a note, this is in reference to KDE's svn2git AKA svn-fast-export

Below is the crash dump, I have removed some lines for brevity

```
The crash dump shows this, I have cut it for brevity

fast-import crash report:
fast-import process: 1907401
parent process : 1907400
at 2022-04-12 16:21:10 +0000

fatal: Root cannot be a non-directory

Most Recent Commands Before Crash
mark :18446744073709551497
data 3309
blob
mark :18446744073709551496
data 3345
blob
mark :18446744073709551495
data 9873
blob
mark :18446744073709551494
data 3634
blob
mark :18446744073709551493
data 3710
blob
mark :18446744073709551492
data 781
blob
mark :18446744073709551491
data 17774
blob
mark :18446744073709551490
data 2247
blob
mark :18446744073709551489
data 13726
blob
mark :18446744073709551488
data 13648
blob
mark :18446744073709551487
data 3385
blob
mark :18446744073709551486
data 12054
blob
mark :18446744073709551485
data 74100
blob
mark :18446744073709551484
data 25138
blob
mark :18446744073709551483
data 13723
blob
mark :18446744073709551482
data 27579
blob
mark :18446744073709551481
data 1878
blob
mark :18446744073709551480
data 2212
blob
mark :18446744073709551479
data 2477
blob
mark :18446744073709551478
data 2095
blob
mark :18446744073709551477
data 2332
blob
mark :18446744073709551476
data 4903
blob
mark :18446744073709551475
data 1995
blob
mark :18446744073709551474
data 2324
blob
mark :18446744073709551473
data 19636
blob
mark :18446744073709551472
data 37760
blob
mark :18446744073709551471
data 13991
blob
mark :18446744073709551470
data 13826
blob
mark :18446744073709551469
data 275
blob
mark :18446744073709551468
data 16181
blob
mark :18446744073709551467
data 15237
blob
mark :18446744073709551466
data 14726
commit refs/heads/master
mark :13843
committer chenmx chenmx@localhost 1182183401 +0000
data 16

M 100644 :18446744073709551614

**Active Branch LRU**
---------------------

active_branches = 1 cur, 5 max
pos clock name

 1)      0 refs/heads/master

**Inactive Branches**
-----------------
refs/tags/AZTEC1_USR:
status      :
tip commit  : 884bb4fad167182c947bb1b511ff21fa9063292c
old tree    : 46a14cc3e4245eafab42d5da2f3205aee65efbe3
cur tree    : 46a14cc3e4245eafab42d5da2f3205aee65efbe3
commit clock: 0
last pack   :

refs/tags/I9R1:
status      :
tip commit  : 058a84b135b8b23eb8226e619a227e91432a4fbc
old tree    : e20fdd049cdbfa188d6ea774b6d41a1d813491c4
cur tree    : e20fdd049cdbfa188d6ea774b6d41a1d813491c4
commit clock: 0
last pack   :
...........
...........
...........
refs/tags/AZTEC2_DVT_RC2:
status      :
tip commit  : e38e4c6d7bc981d3589a8569c3915b7e411c32d8
old tree    : 678f7b6629173383582366a5e877a9e065d29d55
cur tree    : 678f7b6629173383582366a5e877a9e065d29d55
commit clock: 0
last pack   :


Marks
-----
exported to marks-jaguar

-------------------
END OF CRASH REPORT

Any ideas on this one since the error does not quite say whats wrong specifically.
```

Comment: Not that this is a solution but a way to circumvent around this error is to use the '--resume-from option with the command and specify the same commit where the error occured or a commit before that, and it keeps moving forward even then.

Comment: Not sure if that would have an implication on the final git repo after migration.

Comment: This is an internal error. Report it to the code authors—but they may need access to your svn repo, or another one that produces the same errors, in order to debug and fix it.